# Non-measurable function which is Riemann-integrable.

Tags: measure-theory

Is there a non-measurable, bounded function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: Riemann integrable functions are Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Yes but doesn't it require that the functions you are talking about be measurable first ?

Comment: If a function is Lebesgue integrable, a fortiori it is measurable!